# New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error but I cannot understand why?  It says that
A new transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateMultiple(IEnumerable<int> employeesToDelete)
        {

            var listemployee = db.Employees.Where(x => employeesToDelete.Contains(x.ID));
            foreach (var item in listemployee)
            {
                int itemid = item.ID;
                Employee e = db.Employees.Find(itemid);
               // e = db.Employees.Find(item);
                db.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Move `db.SaveChanges();` out of the loop.

Comment: Add a .ToList() to your listemployee , with out the ToList() the Database is queryed on each of the foreach Runs , the Reader still has a open transaction when you are trying to do the save